# Listar valores da tabela aleatoriamente com RAND() ou ARRAY para um Captcha

Tags: php, mysqli, captcha

Eu estou criando um **CAPTCHA** e para isso fiz uma **tabela** com **alternativas** que o usuário terá que selecionar a **IMAGEM** correta.

Primeiro eu sorteio uma palavra.

Exemplo: Você deve selecionar a palavra **VENTILADOR**

E depois eu coloco 4 palavras do banco em **ORDEM** aleatória, porém as vezes pode vir a palavra **VENTILADOR** como não.

**Existe alguma forma de USAR RAND, porém exigindo que ele mostre 1 valor especifico?**

Segue como estou tentando fazer:

```
<?php   $querye = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, palavra, imagem FROM captcha WHERE id IN ('$linhas->id') OR rand(id) ORDER BY rand('$linhas->id') LIMIT 4");

for ($i=0; $i < count($palavras); $i++) { 

$valor_opcao = $palavras[$i]['id']; ?>



 <label for="palavra<?php echo $valor_opcao; ?>">



<input type="radio" name="palavraid" autocomplete="off" id="palavra<?php echo $valor_opcao; ?>" value="<?php echo $valor_opcao; ?>">

                                  

<img src="<?php echo $palavras[$i]['imagem']; ?>" id="img">
                   </label>
                          
<?php
    }


?>
```

Me falaram que da pra usar **ARRAY** com **shuffle**, mas não tenho a minima ideia de como fazer.

Comment: pq não seleciona a imagem correta e +3 (ou quantas quiser) aleatórias, e junta tudo numa query usando `union`?

Comment: porque a ordem precisa ser aleatória exemplo:

Comment: A, B, C, D  ------ B C D A ------------ C A B D

Comment: pode user um order by rand para resolver isso :)

Comment: exato só que quero usar um LIMIT, exemplo, coloco pra mostrar só 4 palavras em ordem aleatória, e as vezes ele mostra a palavra selecionada e as vezes não

Comment: coloquei numa resposta, é mais fácil explicar, veja o exemplo funcionando

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente precisa de duas queries:

- uma com a palavra desejada;
- outra sem a plavra desejada limita a 3 (ou mais)

Depois é só ordenar o resultado randomicamente:

```
(SELECT id, palavra FROM captcha WHERE id IN (3))
UNION
(SELECT id, palavra FROM captcha WHERE id NOT IN (3)  ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY RAND();
```

Pode ter funcionando aqui (o id 3 é a palavra que deve sempre vir) : [https://www.db-fiddle.com/](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pX4Gq7PTVArKkBa1R9WwZ2/1)

No que, o segredo é separa as queries entre parênteses, porque na segunda query, quer limitar a 3 resultados, para ter ao todo 4, e só aplicar o order ao final do `UNION` das duas queries :)

Comment: DEUUUUUU certo muito obrigada